# java.lang.exception.getCause() gets null every time

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, null

In one of the softwares that I develop, I am trying to manage an exception mechanism.

At somewhere of the programme, I do something like;

```
IF(my condition not allowed){
    throw new Exception("My condition not allowed", null)
}
```

I throw null with the parameter of java.lang.exception to understand that this is something not relevant with a programatical error. (I don't have a chance to create my own custom exception, please consider that)

And in the somewhere above the programming I catch my exception like this;

```
}catch(Exception e){
if(null == e.getCause)
    do.somethingThatIWantToCatch();
}else{
    do.somethingProgramaticalError();
}
```

here the problem is; my code may throw something else that I don't know like NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException etc...

At this point I expect that e.getCause() should NOT be null if I get programatical error, however I get NULL all the time and I execute my do.somethingThatIWantToCatch(); condition all the time.

how can I handle this situation and execute my do.somethingProgramaticalError(); condition ???

Comment: Read the documentation; `getCause()` will usually be null.  You need to create your own exception.

Comment: This is a ghastly misuse of the exception system. If you want to catch your own exception, *throw* your own exception. Create a derived exception class, or several.

Comment: Thanks for letting my know but I already know this is not the proper way to handle exceptions. As long as I am working on a strict infrastructure on a bank, they don't let me create my custom exception. This is why I am looking for a workaround. I need a solution of this, not a knowledge of if it is proper to use or not. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** throw an instance of `Exception` (or its unchecked child `RuntimeException`).  You should always find an appropriate subclass to throw, or create your own subclass if there isn't already a suitable one.

Catching `Exception` will catch every type of exception under the sun, including the `NullPointerException` that you're concerned about and other exception types that you're not.  It is always best to be as specific as possible about the type of exceptions you catch, so that these other ones you don't want to inadvertently handle are not handled.

As for `getCause()`, that is generally an exception that is passed into the constructor of another exception.  This will be the case for the vast majority of exceptions you run into.